# Book about vampire army underground

Tags: story-identification, novel, vampire

Book set in a small town, possibly in England, where an undead army is waiting in the sewer.

Most of the book's story takes place inside a hotel, where they find a video tape.

They also dissect a vampire in the basement.
The name Leamington rings a bell but I can't find anything with that?

Help greatly appreciated, it's driving me nuts trying to remember!

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

OOh... I know it. Tip of my tongue. Lepping River IIRC, ends up with a biker dude being good and helping out, some chain saw action, etc.

So I've just dug through a box in my garage, severely inconveniencing several spiders and perhaps a mouse.

Vampyrrhic by Simon Clark, think the ISBN is 9780843950311. The big A has it on the K device free at the moment...

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you soooo much! You are a star!